# How to layout the React components?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am a beginner to react js. How can I create a layout for my components?
In my app.js there are four components such as

```
const app = ()=>{
return(
<div>
<Header/>
<SideBar/>
<BodyPart/>
<Footer/>
</div>)
}
```

In my header component

```
const Header=()=>{
return<div>Header</div>}
```

Similarly ,

```
const Footer=()=>{
return<div>Footer</div>}
```

```
const BodyPart=()=>{
return<div>BodyPart</div>}
```

```
const SideBar=()=>{
return<div>Sidebar</div>}
```

How can I layout them as shown in the picture?.

[image]

I don't want to use any libraries. I want to do it in CSS.

Comment: I would say you have to create two components : Header & Main. And in the Main component, you create 3 child components : Sidebar, Body & Footer. And you use CSS to create two columns : 1 wtih Sidebar, and 1 with Body & Footer !

Comment: Show what styling did you try? Basically at what you need is just plain CSS, same thing as what you did with plain HTML

Comment: Maybe you can put `<Header>`, `<BodyPart>`, `<Footer>` in a row, and put `<Sidebar>` as `float` element

Comment: @kunquan For now I only want to create layout.

Comment: @cadenzah how can I style component ? Can i add classname to component as <Header Classname="header"/> like that?

Comment: Adding a `className` wouldn't work on a component. If you inspect the code in the browser's **dev tool**, you will see the component doesn't exist there. You need to add `className` to root/top level element of each component.

Comment: I would suggest you to create the layout in plain **HTML** & **CSS** first and then try to convert the **HTML** template into a **React** app

Comment: @Shuvo Can you give me example for my question so that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a revised version of what you are trying to achieve:

#### App Component

```
import Header from ...
import Page from ...

const app = ()=>{
  return(
    <div className="app-container">
      <Header />
      <Page />
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### Header Component

```
const Header=()=>{
return<header>Header</header>}
```

#### Page Component

```
import Sidebar from ...
import Main from ...

const Page=()=>{
  return(
    <div className="page-container">
      <Sidebar />
      <Main />
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### SideBar Component

```
const SideBar=()=>{
    return<aside>Sidebar</aside>
}
```

#### Main Component

```
import Body from ...
import Footer from ...

const Main =()=>{
  return(
    <div className="main-container">
      <Body />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### Body Component

```
const Body =()=>{
return<main>BodyPart</main>}
```

#### Footer Component

```
const Footer =()=>{
return<footer>Footer</footer>}
```

I hope this will help you to organize your components hierarchy. And if you now want to style your components, you can do so by targeting the classes: `app-container`, `page-container`, `main-container` or by the tag name: `header`, `aside`, `footer`, `main` etc.

Comment: Thanks buddy. It cleared me a lot. Now I can organize my components .